# How to get the number of characters of a tab in .NET?

Tags: .net, text-files

Is there a way to get the length (number of characters/blanks) of a tab in .NET? I am writing data to a text file and would like to create a table with two columns. Since some column entries in the first column appear to be longer/shorter than others, the second column looks ugly. I tried inserting a couple of \t's between entries, but that didn't fully help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use spaces instead of tabs to format your data neatly in an ASCII table.

The [`string.PadLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk6ydzx.aspx) and [`string.PadRight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34d75d7s.aspx) methods may help you.

Answer (score 2):

Tab width is determined by the program the shows it, there isn't a fixed number. You can easily pad with spaces when writing the file, a string's format supports that:

```
String.Format("{0,-16}", "String"); // align left
String.Format("{0,16}", "String");  // align right
```

Example: http://ideone.com/B4VvC

Answer (score 0):

There is no fixed number of positions for a TAB. Most editors allow you to specify that number.